# Associating large numbers of Items with large numbers of Users in Mongo

Tags: database-design, mongodb, nosql

Say I have tables `Items` and `Users`, which are both in the order of millions. Users can be associated with rows in `Items` via a 1 to many relationship. This is expected to be on average, a few thousand. What is the best way to go about this? I can only think of 2 ways to do it:

1. Create a separate table linking the 2 up. This could end up having billions of rows, so I have space concerns here.
2. Embed the item id's in each User, but then i'd be often pulling out more than I need, and inserting/deleting ID's would also be inefficient.

It seems like it would be a common scenario, so am wondering what kind of solutions are out there.

Comment: You have a model with 1-to-many relationship with each User is associated with many Items. Can you tell what kind of queries (important ones) you are going to make on this data?

Answer (score 0):

Consider two collections (or entities) `users` and `items`. And, they are in a `one-to-many` relationship - `users` is the 'one' side and the `items` is the 'many' side.

```
items: [ 1.. millions ]
  itemId: <id value>,
  name: <some name>,
  description: <...>,
  other_fields:  <...>


users: [ 1.. millions ]
  userId: <id value>,
  name: <some name>,
  email: <some value>,
  items: [ 1.. 10000 ]
```

> **Embed the item id's in each User, but then i'd be often pulling out**
>   **more than I need, and inserting/deleting ID's would also be**
>   **inefficient.**

This is a often used approach - embedding the `items` *id*s within the `users` document. This is done by storing the `items` *id*s within the `users` document as an *array*. For example:

```
items: [ itemId-1, itemId-2, ..., itemId-5000 ]
```

With this approach:

- You can retrieve all items associated with a user.
- For more details of specific item, *lookup* the `items` collection (this can be an aggregation lookup operation which queries both collections as a "join").
- All the related information for a user is within one document.
- For efficient querying, create indexes on the most used query filter fields for the `users` (e.g., `userId`, `name`) and the `items` array field.
  Indexes on array fields are called as **Multikey Indexes**.

*Another Approach:*

You can also consider storing more information (as sub or embedded documents) about the items in the `items` array. For example,

```
items: [ { itemId: <id-1>, itemName: <some name> }, { itemId: <id-2>, itemName: <some name 2> }, ... ]
```

In this use case, the `itemName` is often used when you query a user and related items. This way you can avoid accessing the `items` collection for the item's name. This approach works when the field like `itemName` does not change and mostly stable (fields like item price and quantity can change often, and description might not change often).

> **... but then i'd be often pulling out more than I need, and**
>   **inserting/deleting ID's would also be inefficient.**

When you query for a user (`users` collection), you have the option to ***restrict the fields*** (user related and also items array) to get as result of a query. MongoDB's ***projection*** allows this restricting the fields to retrieve within a single document. This also applies to the items array field - only specific item(s), specific number of items, specific fields for an item, etc.

Regarding the inserting / deleting / updating operations - MongoDB has methods to update a single or multiple fields (including array fields) for a document as atomic operation.

There are specific *operators* (referred as array operators) to work with arrays (with scalar or composite values) - for inserting, updating, deleting and querying (CRUD operations) on the array fields. Creating indexes on array fields will make these operations efficient.